# C# Dynamically Load An Assembly And Use It And Then Unload it

Tags: c#, reflection, appdomain

I'm working on a plugin where the shell dll invokes methods in several other function dlls. Because we want to replace these function dlls during updating, the shell dll has to dynamically load those dll, and when updating, dynamically unload them.

I can do the load and unload part with AppDomain, but I can't find any resources about how to create an instance of a type in the loaded dll and invoke method on it. I'd be very much appreciate it if anyone can elaborate on this...

Thanks!

Comment: is this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-load-assemblies-into-an-application-domain#example) what you need?

Comment: no, Assembly.Load will actually load the assembly into the current appdomain, which can't be unloaded later...I have to create a new appdomain and load the assembly there

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I've just tried AppDomain (CreateInstanceFrom and Unload) without luck; there are two problems: I don't know how to call method of the instance and after the Unload the dll loaded is still occupied (not being able to delete)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the new AppDomain. You can have a look at this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?redirectedfrom=MSDN), You will need to use sub-class of MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: thanks, I've finally got it worked with a new dll containing the target type as an interface; however I still can't pass any arguments cross appdomain, with the error always emerging: MarshalByRefObject cannot be converted to the parameter type ...

Comment: doing what you are trying to do seem tricky. I would consider using some IPC mechanism to communicate, possibly loading the plugin in another process.